# Uninstalling Ubuntu 16.04 and recovering Windows bootloader

Tags: windows, uninstall

I have Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 (I did a UEFI install ) How can i uninstall ubuntu, delete GRUB and recover the stock windows boot loader ?

Comment: I think you didnt even read my question...the ubuntu entry in bios isnt my problem. You suggested me to delete the ubuntu folder from the EFI partition, if i did that i would just stay with nothing to boot . I want to uninstall ubuntu but first i need to fix the Windows Boot Manager so i can boot directly from my Hard drive and not the ubuntu entry...

Comment: As i mentioned i am using uefi

Comment: A quick google search returned the same answer on fixing UEFI booting for windows:  https://neosmart.net/wiki/fix-uefi-boot/

Comment: If you have UEFI, it still is an entry in your UEFI, you just have to choose it. If you do not have Windows entries in UEFI you have to run Windows repairs.